# Add CORS header to redirected URL

Tags: redirect, servlets, cors

I have added headers to the reponse to url but it seems to be fail and the url cannot be redirect due to the following reason
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
public String redirect(HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception {

String url = getWeb(some param);

response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

response.sendRedirect(url);


}
```

Comment: That header needs to be set by the server behind the URL represented by your `url` variable. Note that the attempted content type headers are also completely ignored.

Comment: Is it possible to set header without showing it in the url?